# What are the first steps to become a Chair Umpire/Line Judge in Tennis?

Tags: officiating, tennis

I am addicted to Tennis, I can't really become a Tennis pro or even semi-pro right now. I have my eyes on being some kind of official in Tennis.

Where should I start? - My first guess is LINE JUDGE

I have no idea how to make first step. I don't have the perfect eyesight, I am wearing glasses, but as far as I know that does not mean that I can't be a line judge, I am confident that I would be able to make decent calls.

I did a little bit of research and didn't find that much information, I thought do directly contact ITF, but then I thought I would ask here first.

O and, I am based in Germany and I am 22 years old, student.

Comment: Have you tried taking to your local tennis club?

Comment: I think you were on the right track to contact the ITF about it. http://www.itftennis.com/officiating/home.aspx

Comment: Keep in mind, doing well as an official, especially in something like tennis, isn't really predicated on knowing the rules (there aren't many, and anyone can learn them regardless), but on happening to have sharp abilities on spotting, on being a good communicator, on managing personalities, on the right "management" skills.

Comment: (And note, while off topic to your specific details, for some places, like the US, looks pretty well organized [https://www.usta.com/About-USTA/Officials/becoming_an_official/])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears [this page](http://www.dtb-tennis.de/Aus-und-Fortbildung/Schiedsrichterwesen/Ausbildung) on the DDTB-tennis website may be the path towards more details for Germany.

Google translate suggests that it says:

> Unlike in the French or the British tennis association, for example,
>   there is no uniform line-up training in Germany. The usual entry for
>   interested parties is here on futures and challenger tournaments,
>   which always look for new faces on the line.

It also says

> The German Tennis Association (DTSV) is generally informed about
>   vacant spots and is happy to help.

On the [ITF website](http://www.itftennis.com/about/misc/national-associations.aspx?Nation=GER&RA=ANY), it gives contact info as:

Telephone: 49 40 411 78 0
Address: Deutscher Tennis Bund EV
Hallerstrasse 89
Hamburg
20149

Perhaps write to or call them??